# Regulations regarding fire codes/OSHA for exit clearance for multiple employees in tight working conditions

Tags: law, safety

Can anyone tell me if there is any regulations (referring to the title of my question) that outline specific requirements for employees' exit clearance.

For example:

I'm in a 12' x 23' room that has deep desk furniture lined up against the wall, extending 30" with the person in a chair (add another 30" when pulling out of a desk), mirrored on both sides.  You'd have approximately anywhere between 1'-2' of clearance between each chair if two employees were to pull out of their desks, potentially blocking other people from exiting the room; easily.

I'm working on a floor plan that will potentially have up to 6 people working inside said dimensions.  This situation seems like it could be a potential safety hazard, but I need references to back up this feeling.

Version 1:
[image: Version 1]

Version 2:
[image: Version 2]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What country or state?

Comment: In Michigan: USA.

Comment: @JaneS I just added images to support my example.

Comment: Your best bet is to look at your state's building codes or call your local council.

Comment: Just to address the title - OSHA CFR 29 1910.36 covers some and also references "Occupant Load" requirements defined by NFPA 101-2009, Life Safety Code, and in IFC-2009, International Fire Code. It's better to contact a local engineer or fire marshal.

Comment: Not sure exactly about the Code here, but a single point of egress for a workspace is not very safe.

Comment: Second one makes a better work enviroment

Comment: @DanShaffer It would be the best of both, for sure.  However, at this point it's moot.  They opted for a mix between both and it's pretty tight, regardless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doing a brief Google search, Michigan's [General Industry Safety Standards](http://www.michigan.gov/documents/CIS_WSH_part6_38111_7.pdf) seems to cover what you are after.

> (3) The population of an occupancy shall be limited to the existing exit capacity of a building or space. (page 8)

Looking at page 8 - 9 in that document gives some figures.  Beyond that, it doesn't appear to be any more detailed.  If you have questions, contact the state OH&S governing body.

Comment: .. and/or the Local Authority Having Jurisdiction (typically the town's fire marshal).